# I can't get crontab to run, sudo python3 to run script an issue?

Tags: cron

I have been researching this topic for the past two hours and can't find similar info. I am putting the last touch on a LED sign and I want it to run the script every x amount of minutes from raspberry to update the info going to the sign, lets just say every 10 minutes. I have tried everything with crontab -e and sudo crontab. my question is I have to run the file (mysign.py) from the directory in cd my_python and then from there I have to use the command sudo python3 mysign.py, it will not run with sudo python. I am wondering if this has anything to do with it?

here's some of what I have tried, along with the @reboot as well with nothing.

/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python mysign.py

/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 mysign.py

/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/my_python/mysign.py

/10 * * * * /home/pi/my_python/mysign.py

Comment: i don't think there was suppose to be a slash (/) in front of the crontab line.

Comment: whoops, i did have it without the / my real code, just updated it wrong on here by accident! thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to execute on every 10th minute you need to use `*/10 ...` not `/10 ...`.

Second, entries from root's crontab execute as root, hence their home is not `/home/pi` - you actually need to specify the whole path for both the interpreter and the script:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/my_python/mysign.py
```

Make sure you set it in the root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`).

This, of course, assumes the location of your python3 interpreter and the script itself, if those paths are not correct - correct them before adding to crontab.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, if I search usr/bin/python or usr/bin/python in my file search it does show this - The specified directory '/usr/bin/python' is not valid , could that be causing it? but if I go through usr/ click bin/ I can see python 2 and python 3 /3.4 in there

Comment: What do you get when you issue: `sudo which python3`

Comment: /usr/bin/python3

Comment: And can you execute your script as: `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/my_python/mysign.py` ?

Comment: Then as long as your script works and cron is not disabled, the above crontab entry will work.

Comment: yeah I ran a little test script and its working as well, for some reason it just doesn't want to update the led file, ill have to keep looking into it.

Comment: * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/my_python/mysign.py
if I put this in (no /), it will update it every minute, but replacing the first asterisk with a 2, renders nothing, very odd.

Comment: Unless your cron is broken, `*/10 * * * *` will most definitely execute the following command on every 10th minute (not every 10 minutes! - it executes on :00, :10, :20, :30...).